# Problem with self.width not being assigned a value

Tags: python, instance-variables

```
screen_width = 600
screen_height = 600

#Colors
bg = (215, 255, 200)

# game variables cols = columns \\ rows
cols = 6
rows = 6
```

With the `wall` class I have `self_width = to screen_width // cols`. `screen_width` and `cols` are both clearly defined variables but when I run my code, I get an error that says:

```
  line 38, in create_wall
    block_x = col * self.width
AttributeError: 'wall' object has no attribute 'width'"
```

I have no idea why the two variables aren't executing the math operation and being assigned to `self.width` so I can create a `rect` for a pygame.

```
#brick wall class
class wall():
    def _init_(self):
        self.width = screen_width // cols
        self.height = 50

    def create_wall(self):
        self.block = []
        #define an empty list for an individual block
        block_individual = []
        for row in range(rows):
            #block row list
            block_row = []
            #iterate through each column in that row
            for col in range(cols):
                #generate rectangle based on values
                block_x = col * self.width
                block_y = row * self.height
                rect = pygame.Rect(block_x, block_y, self.width, self.height)
```

Comment: Common beginner typo: `_init_` should be `__init__` -- two `_` at each end.

Comment: …and because the method name is misspelled, it won't automatically be called when instances of your `wall` class are created — so their `self.width` and `self.height` instance variables won't be created and assigned values.

Comment: I dont see where the method is misspelled, my method create_wall() is made once and called in the main function

Comment: Jacob: your create_wall()` method is OK, but before you can call the the method, you must have first created an instance of class `wall`: i.e. `wall1 = wall()` before `wall1.create_wall()`. The problem is when you create the instance, your `_init_()` method **is not** being called automatically because the name is misspelled (so the `self.width` and `height` instance variable were never initialized.

Comment: I got it thanks Martineau